# How to change the schedule of a Kubernetes cronjob or how to start it manually?

Tags: cron, kubectl, kubernetes

**Is there a simple way to change the schedule of a kubernetes cronjob** like `kubectl change cronjob my-cronjob "10 10 * * *"`? Or any other way without needing to do `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml`? The latter can be extremely cumbersome in a complex CI/CD setting because manually editing the deployment yaml is often not desired, especially not if the file is created from a template in the build process.

**Alternatively, is there a way to start a cronjob manually?** For instance, a job is scheduled to start in 22 hours, but I want to trigger it manually once now without changing the cron schedule for good (for testing or an initial run)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The more recent versions of k8s (from 1.10 on) support the following command:

`$ kubectl create job my-one-time-job --from=cronjobs/my-cronjob`

Source is this solved [k8s github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/60039).

Answer (score 36):

You can update only the selected field of resourse by patching it

```
patch -h                     
Update field(s) of a resource using strategic merge patch, a JSON merge patch, or a JSON patch.           

JSON and YAML formats are accepted.

Please refer to the models in
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/HEAD/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions.html
to find if a field is mutable.
```

As provided in comment for ref :

```
kubectl patch cronjob my-cronjob -p '{"spec":{"schedule": "42 11 * * *"}}'
```

Also, in current kubectl versions, to launch a onetime execution of a declared cronjob, you can manualy create a job that adheres to the cronjob spec with

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/mycron
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide the command directly? For future reference and other people googling this. Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you want to integrate this in your answer?
`kubectl patch my-cronjob -p '{"spec":{"schedule": "42 11 * * *"}}'` ?

Comment: You can run it as a Job (and not a CronJob), it will be scheduled immediately and will run to completion.

Comment: Used @SmCaterpillar suggestion but had to modify to something like `kubectl patch cronjob my-cronjob  --patch '{"spec":{"schedule": "42 11 * * *"}}`

Comment: I used the @Michael suggestion, but I've added an extra ' at the end. ;)

`kubectl patch cronjob my-cronjob  --patch '{"spec":{"schedule": "42 11 * * *"}}'`

Comment: I tried to update an existing cronjob this way and even though the command was that it was patched successfully the schedule didn't change. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

From @SmCaterpillar answer above `kubectl patch my-cronjob -p '{"spec":{"schedule": "42 11 * * *"}}'`,
I was getting the error: **unable to parse "'{spec:{schedule:": yaml: found unexpected end of stream**

If someone else is facing a similar issue, replace the last part of the command with -

```
"{\"spec\":{\"schedule\": \"42 11 * * *\"}}"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32661842)

Answer (score 0):

I have a friend who developed a kubectl plugin that answers exactly that !
It takes an existing cronjob and just create a job out of it.
See https://github.com/vic3lord/cronjobjob
Look into the README for installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to do patch a k8s cronjob schedule with the [Python `kubernetes` library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python), you can do this like that:

```
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.BatchV1beta1Api()
body = {"spec": {"schedule": "@daily"}}
ret = v1.patch_namespaced_cron_job(
    namespace="default", name="my-cronjob", body=body
)
print(ret)
```